# How can I process data from a websocket stream and conditionally send a proactive message in Azure Bot?

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, webhooks, azure-bot-service

I have a data provider who provides their data over WebSocket. I need to process it in real-time and then based on some criteria, I'll have to trigger an alert which needs to be sent as a proactive message in Azure Bot Framework.
Now my questions are:
 1. Can we process data from a WebSocket stream within Azure Bot Project and use it to conditionally trigger a proactive message? 
 2. If not possible, what is the best approach to accomplish something like this? Create a separate project to process WebSocket data stream and post alerts via a web-hook? In such case, how can I send proactive messages based on alerts received via webhook?

All my web-searches pointed me to results for sending activities to Azure Bot via WebSockets wr ways to Connect Bot to third-party services via webhook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you would want to create an API in your bot that accepts and processes any proactive messages. You can reference this dotnet [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and this sample, [16.proactive-messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages), for guidance.

For the WebSocket data to be processed, you would want to set this up in a separate service. As a trigger passes thru, the proactive message would be generated and sent to the API you set up to be consumed by the bot.

In short (borrowing from the docs):

First, you create a `conversationReference` which is derived from the `activity` during the `OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync` activity handler.

```cs
private void AddConversationReference(Activity activity)
{
    var conversationReference = activity.GetConversationReference();
    _conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(conversationReference.User.Id, conversationReference, (key, newValue) => conversationReference);
}

protected override Task OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    AddConversationReference(turnContext.Activity as Activity);

    return base.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
}
```

Next, you design the route that handles the incoming request. The `conversationReference` is retrieved and `ContinueConversationAsync` along with `BotCallback` are called to process the incoming message.

```cs
[Route("api/notify")]
[ApiController]
public class NotifyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
    private readonly string _appId;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;

    public NotifyController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
        _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
        _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"];

        // If the channel is the Emulator, and authentication is not in use,
        // the AppId will be null.  We generate a random AppId for this case only.
        // This is not required for production, since the AppId will have a value.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_appId))
        {
            _appId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //if no AppId, use a random Guid
        }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
        {
            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));
        }

        // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = "<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>",
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        };
    }

    private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // If you encounter permission-related errors when sending this message, see
        // https://aka.ms/BotTrustServiceUrl
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("proactive hello");
    }
}
```

Lastly, to avoid 401 'Unauthorized' errors, you'll want to include `TrustServiceUrl()` just prior to the code that sends the proactive message.

```cs
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
```

Hope of help!